# How to structure the code for a Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, model-view-controller, macos

I'm writing a Cocoa application where I have an auto generated app delegate:(MyAppDelegate.h/MyAppDelegate.m)

So I am not sure of the best way to structure the class files for this Cocoa application. I understand MVC thoroughly (on the iPhone) but I'm having a block as to try organising the source properly in a Cocoa app.

I need to spawn two separate fullscreen OpenGL views. The problem is that I could simply create classes for "OpenGLView" then instantiate and call all this code into the app delegate, but it seems messy and it's aparently not the place to do it.
How would I best achieve the code structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your application delegate in the MainMenu.xib file and hook it up.  When I've done Cocoa fullscreen stuff, I've instantiated the views in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of the application delegate.  It *is* messy, because for fullscreen views it doesn't really make sense to use interface builder.  This is the same way that other folks do fullscreen apps in Cocoa.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich. I think you are right after doing some more reading. I'm glad someone could reassure my thoughts on this.